# i want to make my actionlistener on a separete class but it doesnt seem to work

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe, actionlistener

i tried many implementations of adding another method from another class inorder for this to work, but i still cant manage to do it.
so my main is pretty simple :

```
   public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   new frame();
   }}
```

the problem comes on my frame class, when i put my action listener on my frames method, it works perfectly, but when i put it on another class, in this case my actions class, i cant seem to make it work by any means...

```
  public class frame{
  buttons b = new buttons();
  public JFrame f1 = new JFrame("logging in...");
  public JPanel p = new JPanel();
  public frame() {
    frames();
    new actions(); }
  public void frames(){
    p.setLayout(null);
    p.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    b.b1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Pictures\\heroes-icons-large.jpg"));
    b.img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Pictures\\lock screen.jpg"));
    p.add(b.lab);
    p.add(b.lab3);
    p.add(b.lab2);
    p.add(b.b1);
    p.add(b.t1);
    p.add(b.t2);
    p.add(b.img);
    f1.pack();
    f1.setSize(340,300);
    f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f1.add(p);
    f1.setVisible(true); }}
```

ofcourse i made my buttons labels etc on another class which i dont think i need  to write it here, so here is my actions class that seems to have a problem:

```
  public class actions {
  buttons b = new buttons();
  public actions(){
    a1(); }
  public void a1(){
    b.b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            b.lab.setText("it works!");
        }});}}
```

please help me, im kinda new so there might be a few things i dont know / i might be missing, but trust me i tried ALOT. thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need an action class? you don't need to override actionListener. have you implements ActionListener for your main class?

```
 @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ // your code};
```